# Which is correct? "…who copy/copied from who?"

Tags: tense, subject-verb-agreement

Is it grammatically okay to say:

1. Between John and Abraham who **copy** from who?
2. Between John and Abraham who **copied** from who?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Questions of the form “Is *x* okay?” are better augmented with what you think any differences in meaning might be, whether you those may be better than the other, and why you think so. Also, one should indicate what effort one has already undertaken to answer the question for oneself along with the result of those efforts.